# SQL: Showing a Link Option Using Conditions

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript, ado

I'm trying to make a menu option available to users depending on conditions using 2 tables.

We have a directory website for different towns and each town administrator is able to add subcategories to main categories in order to customise their directory structure, but it's currently allowing them to add subcategories to further subcategories that are already populated with adverts - which it shouldn't do.

I would like to only show the option to 'Add a subcatgory' to another subcategory when there are no adverts already added to it.

For example, there is a subcategory called 'Accountants' in all town directories.  It is populated with client adverts in the 'Brentwood' directory, but not in the 'Shrewsbury' directory.

I want to only show the option to  'Add a subcategory', if the following three conditions are met using data from the following tables and columns:

- 'Directories' Table: It needs to be the current franchise town (using the 'FranchiseGID' column)
- 'Directories' Table: It must apply to each individual subcategory (GID column)
- 'Clients' Table: No Client have registered to be listed in the subcategory (GID column)

So using a combination of these table columns, using the 'iAdvertCount' as the counter and 'ClientGID' to check whether there are advert subscriptions in that particular subcategory; also that it's only being applied to the current franchise website (FranchiseGID).

I can select information from one table, but not multiple - so would love some help on how to select the reqiured info from the above columns and tables.

Here is how far I've got with the 'Directories' table, but need to add in the Client GID condition from 'Clients' too:

```
Dim iAdvertCount

SQLCommand = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Counter FROM Directories WHERE GID is not null AND FranchiseGID is not null"
rsTemp.Open SQLCommand, objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
iSubscriptionCount = rsTemp("Counter")
rsTemp.Close
if iSubscriptionCount = 0 then
    %><a href="AddDirectory.asp?PGID=<% = rsDirectory("GID") %>"><% = GetIcon("Add", "Add Sub Directory", 25, True) %></a><%
end if
```

So far I am able to hide the 'Add a subcategory' option on any website franchise (e.g. Brentwood) directory that contains a ClientGID, but it's being applied to all subcategories regardless of whether they contain Client Subscriptions/Adverts or not.

I am hoping someone can help and indeed make sense of what I wrote to assist in some way as it would help a lot!

Comment: What happens when AdminFranchiseGID is `') drop table uvw_DirectoryBrowser_Adverts select ('` ?

Comment: I don't understand this question and lots context is missing and lots of superfluous information is provided

Comment: Sam is pointing out that your code might be vulnerable to a hacker technique called "SQL Injection". Is there anything that the user can enter, which would allow them to set the value of AdminFranchiseGID? Because if they set it to the value that Sam shows you, the resulting SQL command would be: "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Counter FROM uvw_DirectoryBrowser_Adverts WHERE ... AND (FranchiseGID = '') Drop table uvw_DirectoryBrowser_Adverts select ('')" -- which would select some data, then drop a table, then select a constant. Do a Google search for "avoid SQL Injection" to see a LOT more about this.

Comment: Should be able to give you a LOT more help, if you give us more details. What does table uvw_DirectoryBrowser_Adverts look like? Give us column names and data types. Also, how do you tell if a subcategory already has adverts? If you can't tell _us_ what you want to do, you certainly won't be able to tell SQL Server what you want to do.

Comment: Admins should only be able to see a link if there are no advertisements in the subcategory.  I'm fuzzy on how your data is structured.  Could you help me understand the Directories and Clients tables?   Directories has a subcategory of Accountants and a franchise id (brentwood or shrewsbury) based on example. An advert exists for Accountants in Brentwood (recorded in the Clients table?) Do you want to know the advert count per franchise? Only return a list of places that have no adverts? Given a Franchise and subcategory, how many adverts are there? What is the problem we are trying to solve?

Comment: Show the table definitions and I'll write you the query

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping this is more than a proverbial shot in the dark

I believe you need to use an exist operator.

The [exist operator](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php) is used in the where clause to determine if subquery returns results or not.

So your query might look like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Counter
  FROM Directories
 WHERE GID is not null
   AND FranchiseGID is not null
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 'ARBITRARY VALUE'
                    FROM clients
                   WHERE clients.gid = directories.gid)
```

The exists operator takes advantage of a [subquery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575.aspx) that's why we're able to refer to the directories table even though it's not in the subquery's from clause.  So if the subquery returns anything it will not be returned to be counted by the count function

You'll probably need to change the subquery's where clause in order to get it to work correctly since I'm not sure how your database is structured